# Set up sign-in with an Azure Active Directory account using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C Doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

I have created a custom policy in my B2C tenant and I want it to connect to the organisation AD.

I have followed all the steps at the link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom

But, I see this error 
https://jwt.ms/#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C90037%3a+An+error+occurred+while+processing+the+request.+Please+contact+administrator+of+the+site+you+are+trying+to+access.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+c18d72fe-4ebd-4dcf-8b65-d5779a491d18%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-11-20+15%3a22%3a21Z%0d%0a

I have tried everything that i can. But it doesn't resolve. What is the issue. What am i missing.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="CloudProfile">
  <DisplayName>xxxEmployee</DisplayName>
  <Description>Login with your xxx account</Description>
  <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
  <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.windows.net/{tennat}/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
    <Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/00000-0000-0000-0000/</Item>
    <Item Key="client_id">000-0000-0000-0000</Item>
    <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">000-000-0000-0000</Item>
    <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
    <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
    <Item Key="scope">openid</Item>
    <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
    <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_key"/>
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="AzureADContoso" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <!-- <OutputClaimsTransformations> -->
    <!-- <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/> -->
    <!-- <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/> -->
    <!-- <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/> -->
    <!-- <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/> -->
  <!-- </OutputClaimsTransformations> -->
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

User Journey

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInCOmpany">
  <OrchestrationSteps>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="CloudExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />

      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="CloudExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="CloudProfile" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

Comment: Can predict, Issue mostly on configuration side. Try doing step by step again if not works enable application insights and check or try extending your question to add all the details including policy files (by deleting sensitive info)

Comment: @Ramakrishna policy addded! Please have a look!